# Error in post-transaction phase, Tridion 2013 sp1

Tags: 2013, content-delivery

I'have the following scenario:

-Tridion 2013 sp1

-.Net deployer with httpupload.aspx

When I publish a page , all the phases works except the last one, throwing a *post-transaction phase error: unable to load processor*.

The trace in the deployer log shows this error:

```
2015-08-06 16:35:54,475 ERROR ModuleFactory - Unable to create module
com.tridion.util.TridionReflectionException: Unable to load request class, was not found on classpath
    at com.tridion.util.ReflectionUtil.loadClassInstanceWithTypes(ReflectionUtil.java:67) [cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.ModuleFactory.createModule(ModuleFactory.java:109) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.Processor.configure(Processor.java:81) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.Processor.<init>(Processor.java:65) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [na:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0]
    at com.tridion.util.ReflectionUtil.loadClassInstanceWithTypes(ReflectionUtil.java:65) [cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.util.ReflectionUtil.loadClassInstance(ReflectionUtil.java:108) [cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.ProcessorFactory.createProcessor(ProcessorFactory.java:130) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.ProcessorFactory.createProcessors(ProcessorFactory.java:114) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.workers.ProcessorWorker.doWork(ProcessorWorker.java:56) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.CommitPhase.onSuccess(CommitPhase.java:116) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runSafeEvent(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:240) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:101) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:64) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:82) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:180) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sdl.context.deployer.ContextExpressionDeploy
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at com.tridion.util.ReflectionUtil.loadClassInstanceWithTypes(ReflectionUtil.java:61) [cd_core.jar:na]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

For this line I suspect that maybe, there is some missing jar file in the bin directory:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sdl.context.deployer.ContextExpressionDeploy

Or maybe some configuration xml?

Some tip about wich could be the cause?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might need to add `cx_api.jar`, `cx_deployer.jar` and `gson.jar` to your deployer installation.

Have a check through "[Adding the Context Expression Extension to your Content Deployer](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-1E6F175B-85C9-4645-B249-348E5ECF5369)" in the online docs.